# BigInteger to byte array, with size of bigint at the beginning of array

Tags: java, arrays, biginteger

I want to write a BigInteger to a file, but I want to prepend it with the lenght of the integer, so I know how long it is when I read it again (the file wih have several bigints)

I know I can convert it to a byte array using `bigInteger.toByteArray()`, but then to prepend this array with its length the only way I can think of is to create another array and copy it. I don't want to do that since it will basically double the time I would take to write the file, and waste time and memory.

Is there any other, more efficient method?

Edit: Looking at the comments - I'm doing this because I want to put multiple bigints in a single file, and so I can use the length as delimiter of sorts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to prepend anything to the array. Write the length first, and the array right after that.

Comment: How do I find the lenght before I create the array?

Comment: You don't have to know the length beforehand. [`BigInteger.toByteArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray--) takes care of creating an array of the right size, fills it up and returns it.

Comment: But that is not what I want at all. Say, the bigint is 256, then the byte array return by `BigInteger.toByteArray` will be `00000001 00000000`, but what I want is `00000010 00000001 00000000`

Comment: @hoodakaushal sure, so just get the byte array, write its length, and then write it.  There's no memory overhead in temporarily storing the array in a variable.

Comment: Oh, by write you mean to the file. Makes sense now.